# Count if when rows with start and end range include a particular number

Tags: excel

I have a table where two columns include a start and end number for each row or record in the table. In a separate area I have numbers from 1 through 39. I want to perform a count if for all of those numbers so that I know how many records include ranges that would include that number.

So let's say the left column is start numbers and the right is end numbers:

```
7   36                           
8   14                          
8   35                          
9   29                          
10  39                          
11  36                          
13  34                          
13  15                          
14  39
```

I want to get a count of each row that can contain 14. That would include the first row because it starts at 7 and ends at 36 so 14 is found in between. Similarly the next row ends in 14 so also contains 14. And so on.

**Note: 14 is just an example, there are a lot more numbers that I need to check to see if they are in the above ranges. The ranges above are also examples, there are many records that include those range fields which all differ.**

While I know how to do count if for situations where the start and end number is the criteria for the count if (simply a multiple criteria count if formula), I don't know how to do the reverse in this situation. Or I haven't thought of a simple way to do so. Any thoughts?

Comment: In C, `=AND(A1<=14,B1>=14)` provided your start is in A and end is in B, drag down. Then use a `COUNTIF` for all `TRUE`.

Comment: ah that got my hopes up for a second but I realize I didn't explain further. It's not just 14 that I want to know, I was using that as an example. There are 39 numbers that I need to know the countif regarding the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should get you very close to where you want to be.
It will ask you for the two column range of data, then for a cell to output the results.
The results for each rec no scanned for will be listed on a separate line
As always try this on a working copy. Good Luck!

```vb
Sub CountInRange()
  Dim RangeToScan As Range
  Dim RangeToWrite As Range
  Dim NumToFind As Integer
  Dim Found As Integer
  Dim Row As Long
  Dim CurrentCell As Range

  'Have the user show me the range of numbers
  Set RangeToScan = Application.InputBox("Select the range to scan", _
    Title:="Count in Range", Type:=8)
  'Make sure the range is only two cols wide
  Do While RangeToScan.Columns.Count <> 2
    MsgBox ("The range can only be 2 columns wide!")
    Set RangeToScan = Application.InputBox("Select the range to scan", _
      Title:="Count in Range", Type:=8)
  Loop
  'Have the user show me the starting write location
  Set RangeToWrite = Application.InputBox("Select the starting write location", _
    Title:="Count in Range", Type:=8)
  Do While RangeToWrite.Columns.Count > 1 And RangeToWrite.Rows.Count > 1
    MsgBox ("The starting write location must be one cell")
    Set RangeToWrite = Application.InputBox("Select the range to scan", _
      Title:="Count in Range", Type:=8)
  Loop
  'For each number to find
  For NumToFind = 1 To 39
    Found = 0
    Set CurrentCell = RangeToScan(1, 1)
    'for each row in the Range to Scan
    For Row = 1 To RangeToScan.Rows.Count
      If NumToFind >= CurrentCell.Value And NumToFind <= CurrentCell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        Found = Found + 1
      End If
      Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next
    Set CurrentCell = RangeToWrite(NumToFind, 1)
    CurrentCell.Value = "Record " & NumToFind & " was found " & Found & " times"
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: will try it out when back at work. The problem with using visual basic is that my work has to get reviewed and it's hard for other people to know if something was done correctly if it isn't straightforward formulas

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&D$1,B:B,">="&D$1)
```

where D1 contains `14`.

You might want to put alternatives to `14` to the right of D1 in row1 and copy the above formula to the right.